# Dependency for cassandra phantom

Tags: scala, maven, cassandra, sbt, phantom-dsl

I have following `bulid.sbt`

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.websudos" %% "diesel-engine" % "0.3.0"

libraryDependencies += "com.websudos" %% "phantom-dsl" % "1.27.0"
```

When `sbt` try resolve dependency following communicate is showing:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.websudos#diesel-engine_2.11;0.3.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.websudos:diesel-engine_2.11:0.3.0 (/path/build.sbt#L13-14)
[warn]            +- com.websudos:phantom-dsl_2.11:1.27.0 (/path/build.sbt#L15-16)
[warn]            +- default:webscraper_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.websudos#diesel-engine_2.11;0.3.0: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 2016-07-11 18:19:22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of phantom available on Maven Central is `1.27.0`. The `diesel-engine` does not get published to Maven Central at all, instead it gets published to our OSS Bintray repository.

`resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("websudos", "oss-releases")` is the one you need to get `diesel-engine` to resolve properly. This is all described on the wiki page on integrating phantom, available [here](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/wiki/Integrating-phantom-in-your-project).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such version on [maven central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.websudos/phantom-dsl_2.11). The oldest one is 1.5.0. If you really want to use the old one, try to download it from [here](https://bintray.com/websudos/oss-releases/diesel-engine/view) adding this line to your sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("websudos", "oss-releases")
```

Comment: It looks like it is on central though and it is the latest?  http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/websudos/phantom-dsl_2.11/1.27.0/

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood.  Phantom is on central, but diesel is not